# How does AWS autoscaling groups recognize that EC2 is idle and it should be terminated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a flask python program on EC2 which is under Load Balancer and autoscaling. In a scenario where is load increases on one Ec2 it creates another and if newly scaled Ec2 has been idle or not utilized it scales in or terminates it. The problem here is if a single user is accessing newly scaled instance which hardly takes any CPU utilization how autoscaling group will realize that it idle and if it doesn't it will terminate it leaving downtime for that user.

1. I have two scenarios in mind that it  checks for a particular program for a amount of time in EC2 if it is running then don't, otherwise terminate it.
2. I see Step scaling policy but there option is only for CPU utilization that is hardly consumed if there is a single user, not even 0.1 %.

Can someone please tell me whats the best option for me and if these two options are possible then how to do it? I have been trying to ask developers since many days but could not get reliable answers in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 Auto-scaling does not know which of your instances are 'in use'.

Also, the decision to terminate an instance is typically made on **a metric across all instances** (eg CPU Utilization), rather than a metric on a *specific* instance.

When Auto Scaling decides to remove an instance from the Auto Scaling group, it picks an instance as follows:

- It picks an **Availability Zone with the most instances** (to keep them balanced)
- It then selects an instance based on the [Termination Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-termination-policies.html)

See also: [Control which Auto Scaling instances terminate during scale in - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html)

When using a Load Balancer with Auto Scaling, traffic going to the instance that will be terminated is 'drained', allowing a chance for the instance to complete existing requests.

You can further prevent an instance from terminating while it is still "in use"by implementing [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling lifecycle hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) that allow your own code to delay the Termination.

Or, if all of this is unsatisfactory, you can **disable the automatic selection** of an instance to terminate and instance have your own code call [TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup.html) to terminate a *specific* instance of your choosing.

For an overview of Auto Scaling, I recommend this video from the AWS Reinvent conference: [AWS re:Invent 2019: Capacity management made easy with Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling (CMP326-R1) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BlsFNBnKHc)